# Cron is not picking up initctl command

Tags: linux, bash

My script run successfully when i run it manually but when i add it to cron it didn't work. I store the output in a log file it shows initctl command not found. Why cron is not running the initctl command.

```
#!/bin/bash
A=$(initctl status worker1)
var1="$( echo $A | cut -d " " -f2 )"
if [ "$var1" == "start/running," ]; then
echo "worker1 is already running"
else
initctl stop worker1;
```

Comment: it does not know the path to it. Pls check de environment variables.

Comment: will you please elaborate

Comment: Check the ``PATH`` environment variable of the process triggered by cron. That is how the system looks for executables. That is documented. Or you use the absolute path to executables, then the environment variable is not used.

Comment: i have already done this

Comment: Add a line to set the command search `PATH` at the beginning of the script. BTW, this is *always* good practice. You always want to know for sure what value `PATH` has.

Comment: i have solved it. Thank you all.